# Lua program will not run more than once

Tags: lua

This is a program in Lua that is setup to grab a file and read to from the console, but it wont run more than once. I'm new to programing and I don't know what could keep it from running more than once. any help is appreciated

```
local function readfile(name)
    io.input(name)
    local file = io.read("*all")
    io.close()
    print (file)
end
local user = io.read()
readfile(user .. ".txt")
```

found the solution to the entire problum thanks to you all including Egor Skriptunoff for giving the fix to my function

```
local function readfile(name)
  local f = assert(io.open(name))
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  return content
end

  repeat
   local input = io.read()
  if string.sub(input, 1, 1) == ("@") then do
    local ninput = string.sub(input, 2, 100)
    print(readfile(ninput))
  end
end
end
until input == ("stop")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "running more than once."? the code you have shown above does not contain any loops so it will only execute once, to get it to repeat you need to use a loop of some kind.

Comment: wasnt aware i needed to add a loop to make run more than once ty for pointing me in the right direction ill add a loop in after watching a video on them :p

Answer (score 1):

`io.input(name)` sets the input file (STDIN).
`io.close()` closes the output file (STDOUT).
Probably you want to close the input file instead:

```
io.close(io.input())
```

Comment: ty for showing me a more secure way to close my file ill modify it to do so